# Laravel Blade Directives recieve object instead of var

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

**Short version of the question is:**
*Is there a way to send the actual $object to the custom directive and reuse it in a view?*

---

***Details:***

I created a new directive, which is:

```
@object_actions($object)
```

This `$object` is actually an object, and it can be named anything. The directive returns a view with html code, built as a tool to be used everywhere on the site.

So let's say I have a `$post`. That post can have `$post->like()`. It is basically a model, now just like it can be `$post` it can be `$photo` as well, both are models.

Now let's say I am in the photos view, with that @object_actions I can easily embed the `layouts.objects.actions.blade.php` views like that:

```
@object_actions($photo)
```

Same in posts views, I can

```
@object_actions($post)
```

Both are models again, or they can be anything object with methods, etc.

I could simply use `@include('layouts.objects.actions')` and it works. But that's not practical at all, since the `layouts.objects.actions` has this html code:

```
<span data-liked="<?php  echo $object->isLiked() ? 'true' : 'false';?>">
     <span class="likes-count">{{$object->likes()->count()}}</span>
 </span>
```

So as you can see, it uses `$object` as the var name or object name, including this in posts view, or any view where the actual var name is either `$post`, `$photo`, `$comment` is never `$object`, and doing something like `$object =  $post`, `$object = $photo` is kind of messy.

I thought I could create a directive like

```
 Blade::directive('object_actions', function ($object) {
     // dd($object) -- returns a string and not the model 
     // Include the view here
 });
```

However, `$object` is always a `$string`, a dd before the return `dd($object)` returns a string, therefore the actions view throws an error *call to a member function xxx() on string*.

dd on

```
@object_actions($photo) // returns '$photo
@object_actions($post) // returns '$post'
```

I want the real object I sent from the original view.

So is there a way to send the actual $object to the custom directive and reuse it in a view?

Comment: [Have you tried this?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/blade-directive-passing-an-object-instead-of-a-string-as-parameter?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was this:

```
// AppServiceProvider

    Blade::directive('actions', function ($object) {
        return "<?php echo \$__env->make('blocks.objects.actions', ['object'=>{$object}])->render(); ?>";
    });
```